# Rewrite redirects the simple regex to base file

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm trying to do the basic mod_rewrite clean URL trick, where `/category/item` rewrites to `/category/index.php?id=item`. In the `/category` directory, I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase  /category/
RewriteRule  ^(.+)$  index.php?id=$1  [L]
```

It sends the request to the `index.php` script just fine, but instead of finding "item" in the id variable, I'm getting "index.php". That is, `/category/item` seems to be rewriting to `/category/index.php?id=index.php`.

I've tried endless variations, with different/no RewriteBase and other changes, but nothing is working. Any idea where I've gone wrong?

Comment: When you say "in the id variable", do you mean `$_GET["id"]`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. A print_r of $_GET shows `Array ( [id] => index.php )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the file index.php is in the same directory as htaccess and is included and handled by the rewrite. Try adding rewrite conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Also, the input you are passing to the id paramater is very insecure. Assuming you use numeric ids, you may want to use `[0-9]` instead of a `.` to ensure only numbers are passed. If they are alphanumeric, you would still want to use something like: `[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]`.